# Responsive Image Cropped Right

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

How can the following behavior be achieved?

1. Start with wide image e.g. 1440px x 378px.
2. Screen width = 1440px+ image displays normally.
3. As screen width is reduced the right side (or both left/right) of the image is cropped.
4. Screen width = 1024px image is fully cropped i.e no additional cropping occurs now.
5. As screen width is reduced the cropped image reduces in width/height like a standard responsive image i.e. img { max-width: 100%; }

Comment: Please always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a div wrapper:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 1440px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper img {
    width: 1440px;
    max-width: 140.625%; /* 1440px/1024px = 140.625% */
}
```

- Above `1440px` the image will display in full.
- Between `1024px` and `1440px` it will be cropped, but display at 100% scale.
- Below `1024px`, it will scale down, keeping the same region cropped.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MizardX/PB7D5/

If the exact widths are not important, you could leave them off and let everything auto-size. The `max-width` on the image will control the maximum amount that will be cropped.

Answer (score 2):

Does using background image solve your problem?

```
.image {
  height: 300px;
  width: 40%;
  max-width: 1440px;
  background-image: url('http://kaboomshark.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/xbox-logo-600x300.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Then set your media queries to resize or set the new background image url, size and positioning the image as needed something like so: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DIAic/